# How to do distributed stress testing using jmeter on aws windows ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, performance-testing, database-performance, stress-testing

I am planning to run the jmeter script in aws cloud.
I have installed jmeter in windows ec2 instance(rdp connction).
Can some one explain the steps on how to do distributed stress testing ?
How to connect slave and master nodes of ec2 windows instance?
How to run distribut3d load testing using master and slave on aws windows ec2 instance?

Please give me a detailed explanation

Comment: Have you read https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/ensure-optimal-application-performance-with-distributed-load-testing-on-aws/ ? It’s using an alternative to distribut3d it might give you some of the answers you need

Answer (score 0):

AWS EC2 instances don't really differ from any other machines. Just make sure to:

1. Use [public IPs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-public-addresses), not the private ones or make sure that the instances are in the same [VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/what-is-amazon-vpc.html)
2. RMI ports which is used for communication between master and the slave(s) are open in [Windows Firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/network-security/windows-firewall/windows-firewall-with-advanced-security) and [AWS Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-security-groups.html)

There is [JMeter ec2 Script](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2) which automates configuration and setup

More information:

- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)